# Finding an equation of a line through $(4, -2)$ that is parallel to $-5x + 7y = -69$ in standard form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

> Find an equation of a line satisfying the conditions given. Express the equation in standard form.  Through $(4, -2)$ and parallel to $-5x+7y=-69$.

So I have already inserted the equation and coordinates into the point slope formula. But, I am unsure of what to do next. What is the next step in solving this problem?

Comment: You can also determine which slope the line $-5x+7y=-69$ has and together with the point determine the desired line.

Comment: The slope I obtained was 5/7x-69/7. The slope being 5/7x. Do I plug it into the point slope formula? If so, how would I go about distributing it? @Peter

Comment: You have $y=mx+b$, if you know the slope (which is by the way , 5/7 , not 5/7x) and a point you can plug in x,m,y to get b. Another tip : Avoid to write 5/7x , this could mean (5/7)x or 5/(7x). To avoid a possible misunderstanding, write 5x/7 in such cases.

Comment: I recommend that you learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) since it looks much nicer for complex expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can notice the coefficients $A$ and $B$ in the standard form $Ax+By=C$ uniquely determine the slope. Therefore when $(4,-2)$ is substituted, the left-hand side must equal the right-hand side.

This directly gives you the equation of a line in standard form.

Comment: Would I then plug 5/7x into the point slope formula? @Toby Mak

Comment: Using this method you don't need to, because the question asks you for the line in *standard form*.

Answer (score 1):

Point-slope form is $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$, where $(x_1,y_1)$ is a point on the line,  and $m$ is the slope.

The slope of $-5x+7y=-69$ is $\dfrac57$.  You could find this by, for instance,  putting the equation in slope-intercept form:   $y=mx+b$.

Now use the point $(4,-2)$, along with the slope, $\dfrac57$, to get $y-(-2)=\dfrac 57(x-4)$, or $y+2=\dfrac 57(x-4)$.

Finally, standard-form is $Ax+By=C$.  So manipulate the above to get $\boxed{5x-7y=34}$.

Answer (score 0):

In the point-slope formula $y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$, you still need to find the slope $m$. The slope of a line in standard form is given by $-\frac{A}{B}$ in the equation $Ax+By=C$. This can be derived from solving for $y$ and finding the coefficient of $x$ in slope-intercept form.

Can you continue?

Comment: So I found the slope, which is y=5/7x-69/7. The slope being 5/7x. @Toby Mak

Comment: Not quite. The equation of the line is $y=mx+c$. Here $m = \frac{5}{7}$, *not* $\frac{5}{7}x$ as this would result in $y = \frac{5}{7}x(x) - (\frac{69}{7}) = \frac{5}{7}\color{red}{x^2} - \frac{69}{7}$. Now can you continue using the point-slope formula?